# passing timestamp variable to another script as a paramter

Tags: shell, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have script that populates tables with data.
I need to record in another table STATS, when it started loading and when it completed the load.

So in the first script I stored timestamp into variable:

```
**script1.sh**
    dtMODEL=$(date +"%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%N %p")
    ./load_table.sh source1
    ./load_table.sh source2
    ./record_table_load_stats.sh MODEL $dtMODEL

**record_table_load_stats.sh**
   #! /bin/bash
   #
   . /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh

   MODEL=$1
   START_DATE=$2
   echo $MODEL
   echo $START_DATE
   sqlplus -s username/password<< !
   /* this is where I wanna use START_DATE variable and populate table*/
```

when I do:

```
echo $dtMODEL

15-Oct-13 13.56.46.677879674 PM
```

but when I pass it to record_table_load_stats.sh, it echoes

```
15-Oct-13
```

why?

Comment: I need to pass the entire timestamp: 15-Oct-13 13.56.46.677879674 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way shell evaluation works, it will first substitute the contents of a variable, and then parse the command line into space-separated arguments.  To override this, you have to quote the spaces in the variable contents.

Most convenient is to add " quotes around `$dtMODEL`, i.e.

```
./record_table_load_stats.sh MODEL "$dtMODEL"
```